# visudo NOPASSWD:ALL doesn't work. I want to know why

Tags: sudo

I want to use `sudo` without command.
so I did `visudo` and changed the file like below.
(my username is `user.jeong`)

```
Defaults    env_reset

Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
user.jeong ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       LOG_INPUT:LOG_OUTPUT:ALL
```

I logged out ssh and logged in again,
I did `sudo ls` but still needed password. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may find the output of `sudo -l` (or `sudo --list`) helpful

Comment: Having no password set is insane. Might as well go back to windows. Any javascript may invade you now

Comment: Is your account in the wheel group?